# UndeliverableException when disposing and onError happen "simultaneously"

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using the following snippet (in RxJava2) for retrieving a list of URL (from the network), and use each URL for downloading a file.

The `imageService.download()` will run with a max concurrency value of 3.

```
disposable.add(imageRepository.getUrls()
    .flatMap(url -> imageService.download(url)
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()), MAX_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOADS)
    .flatMap(response -> fileManagerService.saveFile(response))
    .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
    .subscribe(file -> {}, throwable -> {}, () -> {}));
```

Everything works fine 99% of the time. But in some specific condition I get an `UndeliverableException`: In particular when the Network connection is not available anymore, `disposable.clear()` is called (this is automatically handled by a `JobScheduler` component).

So what is actually happening is that I am trying to dispose the disposable and at the same time the `imageService.download()` Observable will try to call `onError` (HTTP error).

It seems like the disposing action doesn't "stop" the subscription in the inner `flatMap`.

```
W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloNetworkException: Failed to execute http call
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
09-19 11:37:59.501 23732-23732/app.dev W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.dispose(ObservableFlatMap.java:314)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.disposeAll(ObservableFlatMap.java:514)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.dispose(ObservableFlatMap.java:311)
        at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.dispose(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:73)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.dispose(ObservableObserveOn.java:146)
        at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.dispose(LambdaObserver.java:102)
        at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:235)
        at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.clear(CompositeDisposable.java:201)
```

Should I handle the error at a global level? with ( `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler` ) or there is a better way for preventing it to happen?

Comment: Unless you do a manual, blocking network call, you can't handle such cases per flow, therefore, you'd better off setting the global handler.